# how to go back to the from where method in called?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse, I use shortcut `Ctrl+Click` to go to the function. What shortcut is used to return back from where function was called?

I checked many people suggested Alt+LeftArrow. It didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean _Call Hierarchy_ (Ctrl+Alt+H)?

Comment: @howlger No. if I do Ctrl+Click from line number 11 from where I am calling function. and function is  is define at line 80 . It will go to function() at line 80. how to go to line 11 again from line 80. Also, Function can be present in different class also.

Comment: _Open Declaration_ (F3)?

Comment: @howlger. Call Hierarchy will work somehow. But this is not exactly I am searching.

Comment: You mean _Open Declaration_ (F3), right? If you want to use a different shortcut than F3, go to the preferences _General > Keys_ (or hit Ctr+Shift+L twice).

Comment: It is not open declaration. But Call Hierarchy is something which work. I will check General>Keys as well. Thanks @howlger

Comment: By default, _Backward History_ is Alt+Left and _Previous Edit Location_ is Ctrl+Alt+Left. If this does not work for you, go to the preferences _General > Keys_ to these commands and check the binding and whether there are conflicts. You can also filter for `Alt+Left` and tell which commands you see for that (for me it's only the two mentioned commands).

Comment: @howlger I also have same binding and there is no conflict.  I got what was the issue. Issue was in keyboard I was using (Alt gr) button and I though it is same as ```Alt``` button. I pressed ```Alt``` button next to 'window key' button. It worked.